# Connection between eigenvalues of the Seidel adjacency matrix and the usual one

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The Seidel adjacency matrix $S=(s_{ij})$ of a graph with $n$ vertices $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with entries $s_{ij}=-1$ if $v_i$ and $v_j$ are adjacent, $s_{ij}=0$ if $i=j$, and $s_{ij}=1$ otherwise. Meanwhile, the usual adjacency matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ has entries $a_{ij}=1$ if $v_i$ and $v_j$ are adjacent and $a_{ij}=0$ otherwise. By this definition we can conclude that $S=J-I-2A$, where $J$ is the all $1$ matrix and $I$ is the identity.

I want to ask about the eigenvalues of these two matrices. From the book Spectra of Graphs (Brouwer and Haemers, 2012) they said for a regular graph with valency $k$ and other eigenvalues $\theta$, the Seidel eigenvalues are $n-1-2k$ and $-1-2\theta$.

I understand the relation between the eigenvalue that comes with the regularity ($k$ and $n-1-2k$) but I don't understand how is the relation of the other eigenvalues and how to prove them.

Comment: It depends of your definition of a regular graph.

Comment: How does it depend on that? Can you elaborate? I define regular graph just by the graph where every vertex has a constant number of neighbors.

Comment: I am not sure but you may need regularity in a stronger sense, like the existence of a group of automorphisms acting transitively on the vertices. For instance the graph with 8 vertices 12341'2'3'4' with edges 12,23,34,41,24, the same with 1'2' etc plus edges 11' and 33' is regular in your sense with $k=3$ , but the group of automorphism is small.